# jQuery DataTables - initial search doesn't locate proper records

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

When I enter a search for 'CRUZ', the table displays no results even though there is a name 'CRUZ'. When I add any letter and then delete that letter, the table shows the record properly.

I'm perplexed at why this is occurring. Is there something wrong with my configuration to fix it so the initial search works properly?

debug code for jQuery DataTables: ikehar http://debug.datatables.net/ikehar

```
<script>
  $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span9'l><'span3'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    }
  });
  $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
  });
  $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
    "bootstrap": {
        "fnInit": function(oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw) {
            var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
            var fnClickHandler = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action)) {
                    fnDraw(oSettings);
                }
            };
            $(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append('<ul>' + '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">← ' + oLang.sPrevious + '</a></li>' + '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">' + oLang.sNext + ' → </a></li>' + '</ul>');
            var els = $('a', nPaging);
            $(els[0]).bind('click.DT', {
                action: "previous"
            }, fnClickHandler);
            $(els[1]).bind('click.DT', {
                action: "next"
            }, fnClickHandler);
        },
        "fnUpdate": function(oSettings, fnDraw) {
            var iListLength = 5;
            var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
            var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
            var i, ien, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf = Math.floor(iListLength / 2);
            if (oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
                iStart = 1;
                iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
            } else if (oPaging.iPage <= iHalf) {
                iStart = 1;
                iEnd = iListLength;
            } else if (oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages - iHalf)) {
                iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
            } else {
                iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
            }
            for (i = 0, ien = an.length; i < ien; i++) {
                $('li:gt(0)', an[i]).filter(':not(:last)').remove();
                for (j = iStart; j <= iEnd; j++) {
                    <a href="/ref#sClass">sClass</a> = (j == oPaging.iPage + 1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                    $('<li ' + <a href="/ref#sClass">sClass</a> + '><a href="#">' + j + '</a></li>')
                        .insertBefore($('li:last', an[i])[0])
                        .bind('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(), 10) - 1) * oPaging.iLength;
                        fnDraw(oSettings);
                    });
                }
                if (oPaging.iPage === 0) {
                    $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                }

                if (oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages - 1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0) {
                    $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
if ($.fn.DataTable.TableTools) {
    $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
        "container": "DTTT btn-group",
        "buttons": {
            "normal": "btn",
            "disabled": "disabled"
        },
        "collection": {
            "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
            "buttons": {
                "normal": "",
                "disabled": "disabled"
            }
        },
        "print": {
            "info": "DTTT_print_info modal"
        },
        "select": {
            "row": "active"
        }
    });
    $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
        "collection": {
            "container": "ul",
            "button": "li",
            "liner": "a"
        }
    });
}
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orders').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty that this character "/" is causing all this issue..

Comment: Could you please be more specific, which "/" are you referring to?  Thanks!

Comment: I am getting errors in the console.  I would address this first, Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fnPagingInfo'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing another reference to jQuery DataTables, causing search and filter errors.  Properly working solution below:

```
<script>
  $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
      "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
      "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
      "oLanguage": {
          "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
      }
  });
  $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
      "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
  });
  $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function(oSettings) {
      return {
          "iStart": oSettings._iDisplayStart,
          "iEnd": oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
          "iLength": oSettings._iDisplayLength,
          "iTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
          "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
          "iPage": oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ? 0 : Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
          "iTotalPages": oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ? 0 : Math.ceil(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength)
      };
  };
  $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
      "bootstrap": {
          "fnInit": function(oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw) {
              var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
              var fnClickHandler = function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  if (oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action)) {
                      fnDraw(oSettings);
                  }
              };
              $(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append('<ul>' + '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">← ' + oLang.sPrevious + '</a></li>' + '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">' + oLang.sNext + ' → </a></li>' + '</ul>');
              var els = $('a', nPaging);
              $(els[0]).bind('click.DT', {
                  action: "previous"
              }, fnClickHandler);
              $(els[1]).bind('click.DT', {
                  action: "next"
              }, fnClickHandler);
          },
          "fnUpdate": function(oSettings, fnDraw) {
              var iListLength = 5;
              var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
              var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
              var i, ien, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf = Math.floor(iListLength / 2);

              if (oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
                  iStart = 1;
                  iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
              } else if (oPaging.iPage <= iHalf) {
                  iStart = 1;
                  iEnd = iListLength;
              } else if (oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages - iHalf)) {
                  iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                  iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
              } else {
                  iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                  iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
              }
              for (i = 0, ien = an.length; i < ien; i++) {
                  $('li:gt(0)', an[i]).filter(':not(:last)').remove();
                  for (j = iStart; j <= iEnd; j++) {
                      sClass = (j == oPaging.iPage + 1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                      $('<li ' + sClass + '><a href="#">' + j + '</a></li>')
                          .insertBefore($('li:last', an[i])[0])
                          .bind('click', function(e) {
                          e.preventDefault();
                          oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(), 10) - 1) * oPaging.iLength;
                          fnDraw(oSettings);
                      });
                  }
                  if (oPaging.iPage === 0) {
                      $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                  } else {
                      $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                  }
                  if (oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages - 1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0) {
                      $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                  } else {
                      $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  });
  if ($.fn.DataTable.TableTools) {
      $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
          "container": "DTTT btn-group",
          "buttons": {
              "normal": "btn",
              "disabled": "disabled"
          },
          "collection": {
              "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
              "buttons": {
                  "normal": "",
                  "disabled": "disabled"
              }
          },
          "print": {
              "info": "DTTT_print_info modal"
          },
          "select": {
              "row": "active"
          }
      });
      $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
          "collection": {
              "container": "ul",
              "button": "li",
              "liner": "a"
          }
      });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#orders').dataTable({
          "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
          "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
          "iDisplayLength": 50,
          "oLanguage": {
              "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the entire block of code in the document.ready function:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "sDom": "r>t>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    }
  });
  $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
  });
  $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
    "bootstrap": {
        "fnInit": function(oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw) {
            var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
            var fnClickHandler = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action)) {
                    fnDraw(oSettings);
                }
            };
            $(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append('' + '← ' + oLang.sPrevious + '' + '' + oLang.sNext + ' → ' + '');
            var els = $('a', nPaging);
            $(els[0]).bind('click.DT', {
                action: "previous"
            }, fnClickHandler);
            $(els[1]).bind('click.DT', {
                action: "next"
            }, fnClickHandler);
        },
        "fnUpdate": function(oSettings, fnDraw) {
            var iListLength = 5;
            var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
            var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
            var i, ien, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf = Math.floor(iListLength / 2);
            if (oPaging.iTotalPages = (oPaging.iTotalPages - iHalf)) {
                iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
            } else {
                iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
            }
            for (i = 0, ien = an.length; i sClass = (j == oPaging.iPage + 1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                    $('sClass + '>' + j + '')
                        .insertBefore($('li:last', an[i])[0])
                        .bind('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(), 10) - 1) * oPaging.iLength;
                        fnDraw(oSettings);
                    });
                }
                if (oPaging.iPage === 0) {
                    $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                }

                if (oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages - 1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0) {
                    $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
if ($.fn.DataTable.TableTools) {
    $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
        "container": "DTTT btn-group",
        "buttons": {
            "normal": "btn",
            "disabled": "disabled"
        },
        "collection": {
            "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
            "buttons": {
                "normal": "",
                "disabled": "disabled"
            }
        },
        "print": {
            "info": "DTTT_print_info modal"
        },
        "select": {
            "row": "active"
        }
    });
    $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
        "collection": {
            "container": "ul",
            "button": "li",
            "liner": "a"
        }
    });
}

  $('#orders').dataTable({
      "sDom": "r>t>",
      "iDisplayLength": 50,
      "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
      "oLanguage": {
          "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Placing everything in the document.ready function did not change anything.

Comment: Have you looked into the error reported in the console?

Comment: it references this line  var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();

Comment: I'm working on that now, but I don't think that affects the filtering, it's about pagination of them.

Comment: Im fairly certain that is your problem.  when you type in the search box it errors with each letter typed, on the same line of code.